# Why some AdChoices ads are showing AdRoll instead of Adsense

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, geotargeting

I know what AdRoll is, but I have visited one of the my favorite blog and click on the AdChoice overlay and it is showing AdRoll.

1. Is AdRoll operating a ads network? (I think it is no)
2. Is AdRoll buy the Adsense inventory on behalf of the user? Can they allowed to modify the AdChoice overlay?

Comment: I also facing the same issue. My adsense PVs have also dipped and they are half of the PVs in Analytics. I dont know what is wrong. But am trying to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 2):

AdRoll is a technology platform that is integrated with over 40+ ad networks. We're able to use real time bidding to purchase media for our clients at the most effective rate possible.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the information. You mentioned Real time bidding? do Adroll bid in batch or just for that particular user? Is the AdChoice overlay permitted by Google?

Answer (score 0):

Adchoices is a neutral 3rd party.
It's part of the industry self regulation effort to ensure ad targeting companies are compliant with privacy best practices.

Adchoices is simply a way that any advertising company can provide privacy and opt out info for users. AdRoll complies with the industry privacy best practices.